# Theme not getting set on Main Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-theme

I am trying to change theme of an application dynamically. I have two activities, one is main activity and another is setting activity.

In settings activity I am changing theme from color picker dialog when color is selected, theme is changed. But theme is only getting change for the settings activity and not on main activity.

I tried to send color values from settings activity to main activity , but the app dose not get start up. It's showing only blank screen.

When I did debug, I came to know that its getting stuck on first `if(n==0){}`, and the loop goes on it dose not end.

Not getting what's wrong.

Also may be main activity dose not get refreshed when I come from settings activity. How can I refresh main activity?

Settings Activity:

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

    int no;

    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final int color = 0;
    public static final int color_2 = 0;
    public static final int color_3 = 0;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Theme.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



        final ColorPickerDialog colorPickerDialog = new ColorPickerDialog();
        colorPickerDialog.initialize(R.string.dialog_title, new int[]{Color.CYAN, Color.LTGRAY, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.YELLOW}, Color.YELLOW, 3, 2);
        colorPickerDialog.setOnColorSelectedListener(new ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onColorSelected(int color) {

                if (color == Color.CYAN) {
                    Theme.changeToTheme(Settings.this, Theme.THEME_DEFAULT);
                    no = 0;
                }
                else if (color == Color.LTGRAY)

                {
                    Theme.changeToTheme(Settings.this, Theme.THEME_WHITE);
                    no = 1;
                }
                else if (color == Color.BLACK) {

                    Theme.changeToTheme(Settings.this,Theme.THEME_BLUE);
                    no = 3;

                }
                Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "selectedColor : " + color, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt("color",no);
      //  editor.putInt("color_2",no);
      //  editor.putInt("color_3",no);
        editor.commit();

        LinearLayout theme = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.theme);

        theme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                colorPickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "colorpicker");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Theme:

```
    public class Theme {

    private static int sTheme;

    public final static int THEME_DEFAULT = 0;
    public final static int THEME_WHITE = 1;
    public final static int THEME_BLUE = 2;

    /** * Set the theme of the Activity, and restart it by creating a new Activity of the same type. */
    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme) {
        sTheme = theme;
        activity.finish();
        Intent i = new Intent(activity,activity.getClass());
        activity.startActivity(i);
    }

    /** Set the theme of the activity, according to the configuration. */
    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {
        switch (sTheme) {
            default:

            case THEME_DEFAULT:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                break;

            case THEME_WHITE:

                activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Solarized);
                break;

            case THEME_BLUE:

                activity.setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);

                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Toolbar mToolbar;
private MainFragment mFragment;
private int no,no1,no2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();


    no = pref.getInt("color",0);


    if(no == 0)
    {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    }

    else if(no == 1)
    {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Solarized);
    }

    else if(no == 2)
    {
        setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);
    }

   // Theme.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Thank you.

Comment: When are you creating the instances of `MainActivity` and `Settings`?

Comment: changeToTheme method, in that settings activity is returned when user selects color from color picker dialog. Main activity's instance is not created, when i press back the activity's theme is not chanegd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Settings` class you are writing the selected color into `"MyPrefs"` preferences, but in your `MainActivity` your are reading from `"MyPref"` (without S) preferences.

You have already had the public constant `MyPREFERENCES`, try to use it in the `MainActivity` also.

Comment: thank you.. I changed this but still the problem is same. @ Vasily Kabunov

Comment: Have you debugged `MainActivity` after that? It the value of `no` still 0?

Answer (score 0):

When i changed the theme of the second activity, i couldn't change the first activities theme.
I wrote this code in both activities

```
ChangeThemes.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
```

Just right before

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

It worked!